# Result is different between Crystal Reports and Excel in multiply function

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 8.5. Last week, I got an issue from my client as the converted currency is different in the Crystal Report.
When I multiply the value

```
(350 * 15109.17 = 5288209.50)
```

in the calculator, the result is **5288209.50**.

But in my Crystal Report, the result is shown as **5288209.47**.

Why is the result from Crystal Reports different than Excel or my calculator?

I have attached the screenshot for the formula field I used in the Crystal Report:

[image]

Comment: Are you certain there is no rounding or loss of precision occurring?  You could test for this by placing the two fields being multiplied on your report and then formatting the fields to show as many digits following the decimal as Crystal Reports will allow.